# php encryption giving URL characters

Tags: php, mcrypt

Hi I have a "/" which after encoding is, %2F. And the problem is when I add this as part of the URL and open, throws 404 since there is / in between. So my question is is there any way in php where we can 
1. Encrypt and get a string which never gives any special characters like this
2. have a salt passed to the encryption.

By the way following is my encryption method:

```
$string='16';
$key='ec5dc8c8'
$cipher_alg = MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES;
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($cipher_alg,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND); 
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher_alg, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv); 
return base64_encode($encrypted_string);
```

Note : When I use this particular set of string and key I could generate a string which gives this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

`return urlencode(base64_encode($encrypted_string));`

UPDATE:

Use a standard hashing function to do your encryption. It won't return any characters that can't be URL encoded.

Try something like this:

```
$string='16';
$key='ec5dc8c8'
$cipher_alg = MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES;
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($cipher_alg,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND); 
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher_alg, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv); 
$encrypted_string = hash('sha256', "$encrypted_string");
return urlencode(base64_encode($encrypted_string));
```

Comment: Hi i forgot to mention, I have done urlencode while creating the url actually. hence I get %2F in place of /.
I also want to let you know that characters like + is not creating problem when urlencoded.

Comment: If I use such for example
    $encrypted_string = hash("sha256", $encrypted_string);
is giving a very long string. But my intension was also to generate tiny url

Comment: Ok, change the hash type to one found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php. Md5 is a good bit shorter.

Comment: `sha256` throws notice as undefined constant, you should quote it `'sha256'`

Comment: @Enoba: You can't decode a hash, it's one way--but you can decode a base64_encode with base64_decode.